# Openshift server crashe while executing jira

Tags: openshift, jira

Im using openshift with a DIY cartridge, i set up tomcat8 (with jdk8) and deploy JIRA 7 on it, but each jira tries to load its add-ons, the server crashes.
Here are the tomcat logs: http://pastebin.com/6NMgZ1VQ

I even tried to delete the `jira_home/plugins` but still the same problem.
Whats causing this problem? and any possible fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you are probably using a small gear to try to run Jira in Tomcat8, and you are most likely running out of memory on that small gear. Especially if you are also running a database as part of the application.  You can check this by sshing into your gear and running the following commands:

```
oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt
oo-cgroup-read memory.memsw.failcnt
```

You can learn more about these commands [here](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues).

If you are having memory issues, the only real solution is to use a larger gear size, along with possible using a scaled application to put your database on it's own gear.

Comment: No i'm not running  a database, but yea, the two commands returned a value greater than zero, so i yea i guess its a RAM issue, is there any way to combine 2 gears to use more RAM or something?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to pool your gears resources like that.